# Spring @transactional doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I'm using java Configuration, everything work fine except @transactional, it took me serval days try to figure out, but have no idea why it doesn't work, any help would be a great appreciate.

In UserController.java, i try to call **userService.testTransactional(user, request);**

**testTransaction()** is the testing method in UserServiceImpl, "Long.valueOf("Throw RuntimeException");" is the line which is going to throw an exception in this method, but user get added anyway, it's supposed to roll back, but user record persists

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Resource(name="userService")
    protected UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegister(Model model, @ModelAttribute RegisterForm registerForm, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        userService.testTransactional(user, request);

        return "account/register_success";
    }
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Resource
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    public void testTransaction(User user, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        long userId = userDao.add(user);
        Long.valueOf("Throw RuntimeException");
    }
}
```

**Below are my configurations**

web.xml

```
<!-- Java-based annotation-driven Spring container definition -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Location of Java @Configuration classes that configure the components that makeup this application -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myapp.config</param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- Secures the application -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher> 
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Handles requests into the application -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <!-- No explicit configuration file reference here: everything is configured in the root container for simplicity -->       
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration  // Specifies the class as configuration
@EnableWebMvc //Enables to use Spring's annotations in the code
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.account"}) // Specifies which package to scan
public class AppConfig {
    ...
```

DataConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod="close")
    public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ...
        return cpds;
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws PropertyVetoException {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException {
        DataSourceTransactionManager dstm = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        return dstm;
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDao userDao() throws PropertyVetoException {
        return new UserDao(jdbcTemplate());
    }
```

Comment: How does that even compile?  The class userServiceImpl looks like it should extend something for the add(user) method to exist, or at the very least the add() methods should exist in the class then.

Comment: What's exactly happening? And in which line of the code?

Comment: Let me guess, you also have a `DispatcherServlet` which (also) loads the `AppConfig` class. Which results in bean duplication where one has transactions and the other hasn't and as the one without transactions is closer to the `Controller` it will be used.

Comment: Updated my question, it's partial code, not compilable, testTransaction() is the testing method in UserServiceImpl.java

Comment: @zizibj - You still haven't said what's going wrong. Is there an exception?

Comment: "Long.valueOf("Throw RuntimeException");" is the line which is going to throw an exception in method testTransaction(), but user get added anyway, it's supposed to roll back, but user record persists.

Comment: How are you calling the `testTransaction` method also make sure that you are using a database that supports transactions! (MySQL with MyISAM typed tables doesn't support transactions!).

Comment: Sorry about my careless, just add some more codes to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't specified `@EnableTransactionManagement` on the `@Configuration` class that is component scanning and creating the `UserServiceImpl` bean. Assuming that class is in `com.myapp.account`, then the configuration class that component scans it should have `@EnableTransactionManagement`. Change your `DataConfig` or your `AppConfig` appropriately.

Comment: I specified @EnableTransactionManagement on DataConfig.java.

Comment: @zizibj Yes but `DataConfig` did not create your `UserServiceImpl` bean, so it cannot add that behavior.

Comment: Add some more codes in my question, sorry about my bad english, i create userDao bean in DataConfig.java, @Resource userService in my UserContrller.

Comment: @zizibj With the `@Service` annotation on `UserServiceImpl`, Spring creates a bean of that class if you use `@ComponentScan` with that package. However, your `@ComponentScan` is in class `AppConfig` which doesn't have `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, just tried to move **@EnableTransactionManagement** to **AppConfig**, It doesn´t work either.